# How do I insert new attributes dynamically to xml tags using javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, setattribute

I have some xml like the following:

```
<dict>
        <key>Track ID</key>
        <integer>4896</integer>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Let 'cha Boy Go (DIRTY) F/B.o.B</string>
        <key>Artist</key>
        <string>4-Ize</string>
        <key>Grouping</key>
        <string>www.2dopeboyz.com</string>
        <key>Genre</key>
        <string>Hip-Hop</string>
        <key>Kind</key>
        <string>MPEG audio file</string>
        <key>Size</key>
        <integer>5837048</integer>
        <key>Total Time</key>
        <integer>243121</integer>
        <key>Year</key>
        <integer>2010</integer>
        <key>BPM</key>
        <integer>80</integer>
        <key>Date Modified</key>
        <date>2010-09-05T05:51:23Z</date>
        <key>Date Added</key>
        <date>2010-09-04T15:37:43Z</date>
        <key>Bit Rate</key>
        <integer>192</integer>
        <key>Sample Rate</key>
        <integer>44100</integer>
        <key>Comments</key>
        <string>80.3</string>
        <key>Normalization</key>
        <integer>7646</integer>
        <key>Persistent ID</key>
        <string>D9FAAD3E0203FA18</string>
        <key>Track Type</key>
        <string>File</string>
        <key>Location</key>
    </dict>
```

How do I write the JavaScript to insert attributes on certain tags?

Comment: What's the scope here? Where and how do you read that XML?

Comment: Check out the [Element interface in DOM 3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-745549614). It contains methods for setting attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the xml using `XmlDOM`, use **XPath** to find an element and then DOM manipulation to modify it:

```
var xpath = "/dict/key[. = 'Name']";
var element = null;

// IE:
if (ie)
{
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = "false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML("<dict><key>Track ID</key><integer>4896</integer><key>Name</key><string>Let 'cha Boy Go (DIRTY) F/B.o.B</string></dict>"); 

    // Find the element using xpath.
    var values = xmlDoc.selectNodes(xpath);
    element = values[0];
}
// Others:
else
{
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString("<dict><key>Track ID</key><integer>4896</integer><key>Name</key><string>Let 'cha Boy Go (DIRTY) F/B.o.B</string></dict>", "text/xml");

    // Find the element using xpath.    
    var values = xmlDoc.evaluate(xpath, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    element = values.iterateNext();
}

// Change/add the id of the selected element.
element.setAttribute("id", "aga");
```